# rails generator does not create rspec file/directory in rails 3.2.9 engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

We create rails 3.2.9 engine with the command below:

```
rails plugin new my_eng --mountable --dummy-path=spec/dummy
```

in my_eng.gemspec, rspec was added:

```
s.add_development_dependency "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.0"
```

Run `bundle install`. Then in engine's root directory:

```
rails g rspec:install
```

A spec_helper.rb file is created under spec/.

The problem is that when a model or controller is created,ex, `rails g model my_model...`, under spec/, there is no models directory and my_model_spec.rb were created. We tried to run `rails g rspec:install` under spec/dummy/ and the problem remains. What's wrong with our code? Thanks for the help.

Comment: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7472277/387135

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gotta insert in config/application.rb something like:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.template_engine :erb
  g.test_framework  :rspec, :fixture => true, :views => false
  g.integration_tool :rspec, :fixture => true, :views => true
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => "spec/support/factories" 
end
```

Comment: In engine.rb, we use the exact same code from Brian's: config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec, :view_specs => false
    end. Among 10 engines created, there is one rspec working. Just tried the following and it worked: config.generators.integration_tool :rspec
    config.generators.test_framework :rspec. This code is basically doing the same as what it is in RodrigoOliveira or Brian's. But not sure why the code with do loop was not working every time as it should be.

Comment: What does the :views => true or false mean? With the code above, is factory girl created along with a rails generator?

Comment: It mean that view's specs will not be created.

Comment: Is it erb by default (g.template_engine :erb)?